# How I can SUM data after group by in laravel?

Tags: sql, laravel

Trx Table

```
id | akun_id | total | saldo | type
---|---------|-------|-------|------
1  | 2       | 10000 | 10000 | IN
2  | 2       | 10000 | 20000 | IN
3  | 2       | 20000 | 40000 | IN
4  | 2       |  5000 | 35000 | OUT
5  | 8       | 50000 | 50000 | IN
6  | 8       | 50000 | 100000| IN
```

In above sample record, I want to get "saldo" trx and get the last record in group by "akun_id".

This is my sql query used in laravel

```
$data = DB::select('select id, akun_id, saldo
    FROM akun_trxes
    WHERE IN (
        SELECT MAX(id)
        FROM akun_trxes
        GROUP BY akun_id
    )');
```

And this is the result.

```
[
  {
    id: 4,
    akun_id: 2,
    saldo: 35000
  },
  {
    id: 6,
    akun_id: 8,
    saldo: 100000
  }
]
```

After I get the last record data in group by, then can I SUM that all last "saldo" data ?? I want the result like this

```
135000
```

I know for SUM that "saldo" can use foreach/for, but I want use sql query. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

so sum it in query like this

```
$data = DB::select('select id, akun_id, saldo, SUM(saldo)
    FROM akun_trxes
    WHERE IN (
        SELECT MAX(id)
        FROM akun_trxes
        GROUP BY akun_id
    )');
```

Comment: How I can make it show just the number ? not an array ? can be like that ?

Comment: @DikaAw do you even try execute the query?

Answer (score 0):

Do you just want an aggregation query?

```
SELECT SUM(saldo)
FROM akun_trxes
WHERE IN (
    SELECT MAX(id)
    FROM akun_trxes
    GROUP BY akun_id
)
```

Comment: How I can make it show just the number ? not an array ? can be like that ?

Comment: @DikaAw . . . This should return exactly one row with exactly one column, a number.

Comment: Oh I see.. Thanks for your help